# Sonarqube project tagging via properties

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to set project tags similar to project key (sonar.projectKey) in the sonar-qube.properties for tags to be automatically added during project creation?

I was looking through the docs:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings
and wasn't able to find info

Comment: Which tags are you referring to?

Comment: @DuarteMeneses project tags

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Apparently, this feature is not currently supported: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/adding-tags-to-a-scan-via-properties-file/3985

Answer (score 2):

It is there a bit hidden under Project Information, Description it is possible to add the tags there... I was a bit lost for this myself... SQ is not great in terms of UI. You can type your tags and they will be possible to filter them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via the API.

```
curl https://my-sonar-server.com/api/project_tags/set?project=projectName&tags=foo,bar,baz,mumble
```